# how to customize angular mat date picker input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use a simple date range picker in my Angular app. how to set the width and height of angular material date picker input field.

my html -

```
<div class="no-bottom">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Datumsbereich</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Startdatum">
      <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="Endtermin">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

my css -

```
.no-bottom {
   margin-bottom: -1.25em !important;
}
```

my component -

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-range-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-range-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-range-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [NativeDateAdapter],
})
export class DateRangePickerComponent {
  @Output() rangeChange = new EventEmitter<FormGroup<any>>();
  
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    end: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
  });

  constructor() {
    this.range.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.rangeChange.emit(this.range); 
    });
  }
}
```

need the input field to be same height as the button in the left side, which is 35px[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the width and height of **mat-form-field** host element.
A component styles is encapsulated within the component's host element so that they don't affect the rest of your component.

Angular provides ViewEncapsulation.None :

> The styles of components are added to the  of the document,
> making them available throughout the application, so are completely
> global and affect any matching elements within the document.

You need to make these changes to set the width or height:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-range-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-range-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-range-picker.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [NativeDateAdapter],
}) ....
```

// date-range-picker.component.scss

With styles scoped to the component :

```
date-range-picker {
 // apply styles to a host element 
 .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
   width: 100px;
   height: 35px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alpine. Thank you very much for your response. I was able to change the width of the picker input using the above method. but when try to change the height, it doesn't work.  I used this in my .scss. - .mat-mdc-form-field {
        width: 100px; 
        height: 35px;
    }

Comment: @BhashithaHemantha you can change css of elements by using the inpect tool =>    .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
      width: 100px;
      height: 35px;
    }

Comment: yes that sets the height as well. now I need to fix the alignment with the button.  thank you very much for your support